# calling batch file with parameter in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, spawn

To run a batch file from node i am using below given code and it is working fine.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c','D:/somefolder/bin/tools/caprequestutil.bat']);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('data is : '+data.toString());
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error('error is : '+data.toString());
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

It is working fine. Now i want to pass some parameter to this batch file which is not working for me. I'm trying to simply add the parameters after my .bat file as given below:

```
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c','D/somefolder/bin/tools/caprequestutil.bat -id D:/somefolder/bin/tools/IdentityClient.bin -h 1234-567-8765-4532 -type STRING -attr key value -activate acdvdsfdc count https://someurl/foo -full']);
```

How can i add these params?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

The trick is to send the parameters in the form of arrays like given below

```
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c',"D/somefolder/bin/tools/caprequestutil.bat", ["-id", "D:/somefolder/bin/tools/IdentityClient.bin"], ["-h", "1234-567-8765-4532"], ["-type", "STRING"], ["-attr", "key","value"], ["-activate", "acdvdsfdc "], ["count "], ["https://someurl/foo"], ["-full"]]);
```

Comment: There is `:` missing in the string `"D/somefolder/bin/tools/caprequestutil.bat"`. Next the directory separator is ``\`` on Windows and not `/` as on Linux/Mac. The code works by chance due to automatic syntax correction by the Windows file I/O functions and not by design because of using the correct syntax. See the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output usage help. There is explained in detailed how `cmd.exe` interprets the argument string(s) after option `/C` (run command line and close) or option `/K` (run the command line and keep running). Your solution is in real not correct and just works because of Node.js merges the multiple arrays with argument strings together to a single array with all the arguments.

Comment: I recommend to read the Node.js documentation page [How to spawn a child process - the basics](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/child-processes/how-to-spawn-a-child-process/) as well as the Microsoft documentation page for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) called by `spawn` and the Microsoft documentation page about the [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure.